# How to ensure a file exists on assets folder at build time?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a JSON file `db_seed.json` that I want to use as a seed to pre-populate local database in my Android application. This JSON file is dynamically generated from another data source and quite big in size, so I don't want to include this in version control.

However, each time I build the application, I want to make sure that the build process **check the existence of this file** in the assets folder and **shout a build error** if it's not (to make sure that I don't publish an incomplete APK). Is it possible to configure Gradle in Android Studio to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
if (!file('./app/assets/db_seed.json').exists()) {
    logger.log(LogLevel.ERROR, "file not foun")
    throw new GradleException("file not found")
}
```